# Accessing property of an object whose type is known at runtime

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I have an object whose base type is exposed to be at compile time, but whose runtime type is internal and for all practical purposes I am unable to get to the type at compile time.

However, I want to be able to access a property on its instance at runtime.

I understand that without knowing the type at compile time, I cannot create a typed delegate.

What is the most performant way of accessing this property? DynamicInvoke?

Imagine this is a file: Hidden.cs

```
 internal class Hidden
 {
     public string SomeProp { get { .. } }
 }
```

I can't type the following in my code Func someExpression = Expression.Lambda < Func < Program, string > > ...

I just want to confirm that my only option is DynamicInvoke when I can't reference the type at compile time.

Comment: Why you can't get value of property via reflection?

Comment: Performance. I'd rather just use DynamicInvoke on the expression.

Comment: You know what is the return type of the property in compile time? If not how you're going to use it?

Comment: When you  will cache `PropertyInfo` perfromance wouldn't be bad one. Consider also `dynamic` - I think it's faster than `DynamicInvoke` - I've done some performance tests, I'll try to find resuls report.

Comment: I know the return type of the property, but I don't know the Type of the class it is on. I'll add some code.

Comment: dynamic doesn't work, as it'll try to create a typed-delegate on the base type, which I don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `Func<object, string>`, then cast the `object` to `Hidden`(your type) and then access `SomeProp`. All of this can be done in Expressions like this:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static Func<object, string> somePropFunc;
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Create instance somehow
        Type type = typeof(Hidden);
        object hiddenInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        //Cache the delegate in static field, and use it any number of times
        somePropFunc = GetSomePropAccessorMethod();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            // Access Hidden.SomeProp
            Console.WriteLine(somePropFunc(hiddenInstance));
        }
    }

    private static Func<object, string> GetSomePropAccessorMethod()
    {
        Type type = typeof(Hidden);
        PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty("SomeProp");
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "hidden");
        var castHidden = Expression.TypeAs(parameter, type);
        var propertyAccessor = Expression.Property(castHidden, prop);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<object, string>>(propertyAccessor, parameter).Compile();
    }

}

internal class Hidden
{
    public string SomeProp
    {
        get
        {
            return "Some text";
        }
    }
}
```

Which prints "Some text" in  console 100 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a `dynamic`delegate, such as a `Func<dynamic,T>`, with T being your return type. But remember that dynamic dispatching is "slow", as it uses reflection behind the scènes. DynamicInvoke does exactly the same thing, so it's just as slow.

Now remember that "slow" is very relative. It is slow compared to a static invocation, which is nearly instant, but this kind of micro-optimization is hardly ever noticeable in a real program.

Moreover, why do you need to call a property of an object of unknown type in the first place? It sounds to me like a symptom of a bad design decision somewhere down the road. Consider for instance having the relevant types inherit from a common base class/implement the same interface, and suddenly your problem disappears. And you get better performances as a bonus.

**edit**

I didn't realize at first that you wanted to access a member you should not be able to see. Then reflexion is your only hope. And you will need to run your code in full trust too. Just remember that the original creator of the class decided not to give you access to this member and he could have very good reasons for that. You shouldn't do that unless you really REALLY can't do otherwise.

Comment: Long story, I need to access a property on a class that is internal, and I don't own that code. It's one of those times when you just need to do it ...

Comment: @user986697 : a pretty ugly situation to be in. If you have no choice, use reflexion, cache the reflexion object you use (typically `PropertyInfo`) to reduce the overhead and pray the library owner never changes the internals of his Library (something that should not be a breaking change but will break YOU).